# execl() and system() does not work in fedora 22

Tags: c++, c, linux, fedora

I create a simple application to execute .bundle file using fork(). I tested on ubuntu 14 and centos 5 it work fine. It will prompt a terminal that show the installation of the file. But when i test on fedora 22 it does not work. No terminal will show up. It only will work if i run my application directly from terminal. If i double click the application it would not work. I try with both execl() and system() both does not work.Can anyone help me on this. Below is my code

```
int status;
pid_t child_pid = fork();

if(child_pid < 0)
{
    printf("fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (child_pid != 0)
{
    printf("parent process\n");
    wait(NULL);
    //waitpid(child_pid,&status,0); 

    if (WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        printf("signal exit\n");

        exit(0);
    }
}
else if (child_pid == 0) 
{
    printf("child process\n");

    int err = 0;

    err = execlp("/tmp/test.bundle", NULL);
    if( err != 0)
        printf("Error execl : %d",err);


    //system("/tmp/test.bundle");


    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: When `execlp` fails, check `errno` for more details.

Comment: i already check but nothing return from errno. Which mean the execlp execute successfully.

Comment: `errno` always has a value. (It's a variable and doesn't "return" anything.) If `execlp` executes successfully it doesn't return at all (there's nothing for it to return to). If it returns, it returns `-1` because it failed and sets `errno` to a relevant error code.